# Migration from jfxmobile Gradle to Gluon Client Maven plugin

Tags: gluon-mobile, graalvm-native-image

I try to migrate my project based on the jfxmobile Gradle plugin to new Gluon Client Maven plugin. I proceed as follows:

- I generated a project with a same names structure as old project in
  NetBeans.
- I deleted src folder and replaced with the original src
  folder.
- I modified the generated pom.xml and did small refactoring of the old
  code (charm down → attach).
- The project is buildable and runnable in
  NetBeans `(javafx:run)`.

Unfortunately, the project is not possible to build `(client:build)` by Client Plugin. I get a following error message:

```
Command Line

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/graalvm-ce-java11-20.2.0.hotfix-xcode12/bin/native-image -Djdk.internal.lambda.eagerlyInitialize=false --no-server -H:+ExitAfterRelocatableImageWrite -H:+SharedLibrary -H:+AddAllCharsets -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces -H:-DeadlockWatchdogExitOnTimeout -H:DeadlockWatchdogInterval=0 -H:+RemoveSaturatedTypeFlows --features=org.graalvm.home.HomeFinderFeature -H:TempDirectory=/Users/jansvanda/NetBeansProjects/Mircom/target/client/x86_64-darwin/gvm/tmp -H:EnableURLProtocols=http,https -H:ReflectionConfigurationFiles=/Users/jansvanda/NetBeansProjects/Mircom/target/client/x86_64-darwin/gvm/reflectionconfig-x86_64-darwin.json -H:JNIConfigurationFiles=/Users/jansvanda/NetBeansProjects/Mircom/target/client/x86_64-darwin/gvm/jniconfig-x86_64-darwin.json -H:ResourceConfigurationFiles=/Users/jansvanda/NetBeansProjects/Mircom/target/client/x86_64-darwin/gvm/resourceconfig-x86_64-darwin.json -H:IncludeResourceBundles=com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/resources/controls,com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/resources/controls-nt,com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumMessagesBundle -Dsvm.platform=org.graalvm.nativeimage.Platform$DARWIN_AMD64 -cp /var/folders/y5/ygljmqhx2zn3k_3bhpq_5k040000gn/T/classpathJar2836091888120816017.jar com.kojojo.mires.Mircom

Output

Warning: Ignoring server-mode native-image argument --no-server.
[com.kojojo.mires.mircom:30167]    classlist:  10,890.77 ms,  0.96 GB
Error: Method 'com.kojojo.mires.Mircom.main' is declared as the main entry point but it can not be found. Make sure that class 'com.kojojo.mires.Mircom' is on the classpath and that method 'main(String[])' exists in that class.
com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError$UserException: Method 'com.kojojo.mires.Mircom.main' is declared as the main entry point but it can not be found. Make sure that class 'com.kojojo.mires.Mircom' is on the classpath and that method 'main(String[])' exists in that class.
    at com.oracle.svm.core.util.UserError.abort(UserError.java:79)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.buildImage(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:311)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.build(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:508)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:114)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner$JDK9Plus.main(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:537)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.kojojo.mires.Mircom.main([Ljava.lang.String;)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(Class.java:2475)
    at com.oracle.svm.util.ReflectionUtil.lookupMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:58)
    at com.oracle.svm.hosted.NativeImageGeneratorRunner.buildImage(NativeImageGeneratorRunner.java:309)
    ... 3 more
Error: Image build request failed with exit status 1
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: You have to add the `main()` method to your application class.

Comment: It solves the issue thank's